# Компиляция через коммандную строку в Mono

Tags: windows, mono, консоль, компиляция

1. Есть файл `*.cs`
2. Есть *Mono for Windows* установленный в: "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8`"

---

**Задача:** Скомпилировать файл через консоль `Windows` (но не через *консоль Mono*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Это сильно зависит от того, какая логика реализована в файле `*.cs`.*

> - В простейшем случае достаточно запуска `gmcs File.cs` из командной строки.
> - Более сложные случаи, когда необходимо подключать дополнительные `packag'и` и, вообще говоря, развлекаться с настройками компилятора, описаны [**здесь.**](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics)

Comment: На сайте Mono есть вот такая [штука][1]. Там написано как это делается через консоль *Mono* т. е. из консоли *Windows*, но запущенной с **какими - то параметрами**. А вот как это сделать прямо из консоли Windows, т. е. из `C:/Users/User>` я не понимаю.

[1]: http://www.mono-project.com/Using_Mono_on_Windows

Comment: И `gmcs` из консоли не выполняется.

Comment: А что если выяснить какие именно эти *какие-то параметры* (setenv, небось)?

Comment: @karmadro4 нет, всё немного по другому.

Answer (score 2):

***Догадался сам:***

---

Если *ковырять* ярлык, то консоль запускается так:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin\setmonopath.bat"
```

Рабочая папка: `system32`

Открыв файл по адресу:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin\setmonopath.bat
```

Выясняется, что

```
PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\bin;%PATH%
```

Судя по руководству, компиляцию выполняет файл `mcs`. Значит **компилировать надо так:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\bin\mcs *.cs
```

---

Если где ошибся, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Еще вы можете раз и навсегда прописать `C:\...\Mono\bin\` в `PATH` и использовать его без указания полного пути и инвариантно относительно установленной версии `SDK`. *Собственно, так обычно все и делают)*

Comment: > нет, всё немного по другому

По мне, так совершенно типичный `setenv.bat`.